# Combination formula for for large N and limiting value

Tags: combinatorics

Is there any limiting value for (n choose n/2)/2^n as n approaches infinity

viz.
as n -> ∞ what is  (n C (n/2))/2^n assuming n is even.

When I numerically calculate I found it slowly diminishing value w.r.t n.

Thanks in Advance!
MM

Comment: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+n+-%3E+infinity+of+C(n,n%2F2)%2F2%5En) gives the limit as $0$. Though of course, Wolfram isn't foolproof and I have no clue offhand how one might rigorously prove this.

Comment: Assuming $n$ is even, if you toss $n$ coins, then $\frac{\binom{n}{n/2}}{2^n}$ is the probability that _exactly_ half of them gives you heads. Intuitively, it seems reasonable that this goes towards $0$ as $n$ grows. But I can't think of a simple, rigorous argument right now.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\binom{n}{\frac{n}2}\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n!}{\left(\left(\frac{n}2\right)!\right)^2}\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}{\left(\sqrt{\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{2e}\right)^{\frac{n}2}\right)^2}\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}{\pi n\left(\frac{n}{2e}\right)^n}\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} \cdot 2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}\right)\\
&=0\\
\end{align}$$